# Merge Function In Entity FrameWork?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, merge, objectcontext

In NHibernate there is a merge function that does the following:

- if there is a persistent instance with the same identifier currently associated with the session, copy the state of the given object onto the persistent instance
- if there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, try to load it from the database, or create a new persistent instance
- the persistent instance is returned

Is this possible in EF?  I mean this part : copy the state of the given object onto the persistent instance.  And if i used ApplyCurrentValues it seemes to be as update behavior or not?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [ObjectQuery.MergeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.mergeoption.aspx).